# ASP.NET & IIS application pools - any reasons not to create a pool for each app?

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool, w3wp

I understand that having *one app pool per app* helps isolate errors in one app from impacting other apps.

However, sometimes apps are configured to *share the same pool*.

Is there any benefit to this, other than having the (memory?) overhead of one-app-per-pool?

Does this configuration permit scenarios not possible in *one-app-per-pool*?
Maybe in-pool inter-process  communication? (Or rather, inter-app communication, since the apps share the same `w3wp` worker process)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no inter-app communication benefit (specifically, if you have two applications in the same pool which both happen to load the exact same dll file, it will still load it twice, you're not saving there).

The advantage is in managing resource limitations.  Letting two apps share 500MB is more flexible than each app getting its own 250MB (or my personal favourite way of describing this, you're better off with 2 bathrooms for 4 people, than 1 bathroom for 2 people).  You lose isolation, but you gain some headroom on resources (assuming the two applications peak at different times).